# how to modify html in a struts...links to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am new to struts and I am not sure of jsp either. I am a php scripter with JS and C# experience and various other language including java but not the struts or jsp component.

I am confused as to how I can modify the html of a struts file once I have found the config in xml and the jsp linking to it.

Comment: You can add HTML snippets/tags in a JSP file. What html do you want to add and also add the relevant content of the jsp file.

Comment: there is an existing jsp file and it has all html and such...I would just like to modify the html a bit so that I may add an additional navigation option to the menu.

Comment: So why are you unable to modify the html? I guess I am not understanding the dilemma here.

Comment: I dont exactly know where to find the html...The issue is that ive never worked with struts or jsp before so it was hard enough searching through the xml to find config and then the jsp filename that someone told me contains the html...Apparently the html isn't sitting there....Its created when the program runs

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your JSP ... provided that it is not extremely large (which I'm guessing it is not, if it really has no HTML in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPs are typically where you would look for HTML. So, you can usually just open the JSP and edit the HTML.

However, if the HTML is being generated dynamically, you may not see it there. There should be a Tag or Java Scriptlet that should give you some indication of where the HTML is coming from, though.

Comment: the xml struts-config can be viewed here:
http://pastebin.com/hnY55Lce

From there I found a jsp file line like this:
<action name="DashBoardForm" path="/DashBoard" type="com.manageengine.servicedesk.dashboard.action.DashBoardAction">
            <forward name="viewDashBoard" path="/dashboard/Dashboard.jsp"/>

</action>

The problem is nowhere in my file folder do I see Dashboard.jsp

Comment: Ahhh, i see what you mean. You can't find the JSP file at all. You should have a folder in your project for web content ... so maybe "WebContent", or "web", which should have a "dashboard" directory under it. You should be able to find it there. If not, than I'm stumped. Somewhere in your Java project there should be a "Dashboard.jsp".

Comment: there isnt any folder named web but there are about 156 .jar files...Dont know How I could extract them all or if any of those file have that folder in them.

Comment: I don't think the JSP files would be within a JAR, that is not something commonly done (if possible at all). If you want to look in the JAR file, you can open them with something like WinZip or WinRAR.